# Make hair fall without combing?

Tags: particles, hair

I have an animal with hair like Suzanne's. Is there any way to manipulate the hair particles so they respond to gravity right off the bat?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can run a dynamic hair simulation. In the *Particle Systems* tab in the *Properties panel*, check *Hair dynamics*.

[image]

Key *Alt + A* to play. The hair should fall. You can adjust the settings shown above to differ how it falls.

### Further Reading

I learned my stuff from [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-358359.html). You can also look into the [Blender Reference Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/hair/hair_dynamics.html) and YouTube videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=potzBrWqDfo).